# How to setup permalink for blog url in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom structure url for wordpress permalinks. How to setup the permalinks like /blog/%category%/%postname%. but this permalink structure is not working.

For example blog url should be:

```
/blog/categoryname/postname
```

Comment: Have you tried https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks ?

Comment: yes i have tried it but it still redirecting blog/category/categoryname/

Answer (score 0):

Please do like that. In Permalink Settings:

1. Select Custom Structure
2. Put /blog/%category%/%postname%
3. Save and see result

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have this in your Permalink Settings under Custom structure:

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%
```

But it is redirecting your urls to this form:

```
blog/category/categoryname/postname
```

You will have to use a third-party plugin, which will remove the 'category' base, but it will leave the categoryname term.

Try this one - https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-base-littlebizzy/
- it will remove the category base so you will be able to use the custom structure you desired.